# Deductive logic counter-intuitive result

Tags: logic, proof-verification, natural-deduction, automated-theorem-proving

I am working on a small proof in deductive logic. Here is what must be proved:

$(\exists x \in T \mid A \implies P(x)) \implies A \implies (\forall x \in T \mid P(x))$

To me that looks unprovable and even false in term of classical logic, but I am using Tutch (http://www2.tcs.ifi.lmu.de/~abel/tutch/ for those who don't know it) which actually tells me it is true.

```
proof nonsense : (?x:t.(A => P(x))) => A => !x:t.P(x) =
begin
[?x:t.(A => P(x));
    [A;
        [a:t;
            [a:t, A => P(a);
                P(a)];
            P(a)];
        !x:t.P(x)];
    A => !x:t.P(x)];
(?x:t.(A => P(x))) => A => !x:t.P(x)
end;
```

Tutch returns me QED, meaning that the proof is correct. Although it looks like a scoping error.

Did I just find a bug in Tutch or is this actually true in deductive logic?

Thank you!

Comment: Assuming `!` is the universal quantifier and `?` is the existential quantifier, the third line looks like an Existential Elimination to witness `a` while the seventh line appears to be a Universal Introduction from `a`.  That's not sound: `a` is not arbitrary.

Comment: If I'm interpreting your symbols correctly, then classically the statement is equivalent to $$\bigg(\lnot A\bigg) \lor \bigg(\forall x \in T ~:~ \lnot P(x)\bigg) \lor \bigg(\forall x \in T ~:~ P(x)\bigg)$$ which is definitely not a tautology.

Comment: Using => and $\implies$ is a typo, I will correct it.

Comment: From what you are saying, Tutch's scoping definitely is buggy. I expected confirmation that the statement is unprovable, I'm just surprised by the blasphemies that this bug can make Tutch wrongly prove.

Comment: Kinda scary when your theorem verifier is buggy.

Comment: @Olivier: It basically makes variables useless -- if you instantiate $A$ to true and $P(x)$ to $x=y$ you can prove $\forall x,y.x=y$ (since clearly $\exists x.x=y$), so the resulting proof system is not sound for any interpretation with more than one individual. On the other hand, in a structure with one element, quantifiers do nothing -- so the effect is to collapse everything to propositional logic.

Comment: Yes, you've found a bug. But it's not very surprising, since according to your link, the Tutch system was in an early stage of development in March 2005 and hasn't moved on since then.

Comment: Btw, intuitionist logic is strictly weaker than classical logic.  Anything false in classical logic is either false or undefined in intuitionist logic.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As far as I can tell, your 'proof' involves an existential elimination to witness ($a$), then universal introduction to discharge this witness.   This is **not valid**, because a witness is not an arbitrary value.

$\require{enclose}\require{cancel}\begin{array}{l|l:l:l}
1 & \exists x\in T: (A \to P(x)) & \text{assume} & +1
\\ \quad 2 & \quad A & \text{assume} & +2
\\ \qquad 3. & \qquad A \to P(a) & 1,\exists{-} & +3\vert^{x\in T}_{a:\textsf{witness}}
\\ \qquad\quad 4. & \qquad\quad P(a) & 2,3,\to{-}
\\ \hdashline \qquad 5. & \qquad \forall x\in T: P(x) & 4,a,\enclose{circle}[mathcolor="red"]{\forall{+}} & -3\vert^{x\in T}_{a:\enclose{circle}[mathcolor="red"]{\textsf{witness}}}
\\ \hdashline \quad 6. & \quad A \to \forall x\in T:P(x) & 2, 5, \to{+} & -2
\\ \hline 7. & (\exists x\in T:(A \to P(x))) \to (A \to \forall x\in T:P(x)) & 1,6,\to{+} & -1
\end{array}$

Answer (score 0):

This [tree proof generator](https://www.umsu.de/logik/trees/) provides the following countermodel:

[image]

One can make the consequent false by assigning $A$ the value true and letting $P$ be true for only one of the two members of the domain. Since there exists a member of the domain for which $P$ is true, namely $a$, the antecedent is true.

---

Tree Proof Generator. https://www.umsu.de/logik/trees/